# how to find necessary multiplier for loop?

Tags: c++, math

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

  float result = 50.0f;
  float multiplier = 0.5f;
  float fixed_multiplier = 1.0f - multiplier * 0.001f;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    result *= fixed_multiplier;
  }

  cout << result << endl; // 30.322 -- want approximately 25
}
```

After the 1000 iterations, I want `result` to equal `multiplier*result` (`result==25`). How do I find what I need to modify multiplier (in `fixed_multiplier`) to get the desired result?

Comment: Currently, `result *= fixed_multiplier` gives me 30.322 after 1000 iterations. This is wrong, I want it to give me approximately 25. Or before the 1000 iterations, `result*multiplier==25`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `for` loop is summarized by this mathematical equation:

```
result * fixed_multiplier ^ 1000 = result * multiplier
```

You can [solve this equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20*%20x%5E1000%20=%20y%20/%20n) to find your answer.

You can get the same result in C using the `pow` function:

```
fixed_multiplier = pow(multiplier, 0.001);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the following relationship:

```
result_out = result * fixed_multiplier^1000
```

where `^` denotes "to the power of".  Simple algebra gives you this:

```
fixed_multiplier = (result_out / result) ^ (1/1000)
```